# valgrind checking simple multithreading c++11 get sig11 error

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, valgrind

I use valgrind to check a simple c++11 multithreading program. It suppose not get any error but it does.

source code as following

```
// test_main.cpp

#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::mutex gMutex;

void PrintLoop(const std::string& str, const uint32_t& time)
{
    for (uint32_t i=0; i<time; i++) {
        gMutex.lock();
        std::cout << str << ": " << i << std::endl;
        gMutex.unlock();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::thread t0(&PrintLoop, "Thread0", 100);
    std::thread t1(&PrintLoop, "Thread1", 100);

    t0.join();
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I use MacOS, and I compile the source code with following command

```
g++ --std=c+=11 -g test_mian.cpp
```

and execute with following command

```
valgrin ./a.out
```

I got following error

```
==5003== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==5003==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x700002ED903E
==5003==    at 0x10053A351: _pthread_find_thread (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==5003==    by 0x10053B835: _pthread_join_cleanup (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==5003==    by 0x10053B7C3: pthread_join (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==5003==    by 0x10005BE94: std::__1::thread::join() (in /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib)
==5003==    by 0x10000145B: main (test_main.cpp:21)
==5003==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==5003==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==5003==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==5003==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==5003==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==5003==
==5003== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5003==     in use at exit: 26,424 bytes in 188 blocks
==5003==   total heap usage: 259 allocs, 71 frees, 32,336 bytes allocate
==5003==

Memcheck: mc_leakcheck.c:1106 (void lc_scan_memory(Addr, SizeT, Bool, Int, Int, Addr, SizeT)): Assertion 'bad_scanned_addr >= VG_ROUNDUP(start, sizeof(Addr))' failed.

host stacktrace:
==5003==    at 0x238041866: ???
==5003==    by 0x238041C72: ???
==5003==    by 0x238041C55: ???
==5003==    by 0x238002FB1: ???
==5003==    by 0x23800288C: ???
==5003==    by 0x2380016DD: ???
==5003==    by 0x23800EACD: ???
==5003==    by 0x23804D221: ???
==5003==    by 0x2380CB127: ???

sched status:
  running_tid=1
```

Why would this happend? Is there anything wrong with this source code?

Comment: I don't see a problem with your code.  I can run it in valgrind under Linux with gcc 5.4.0 without errors.  Passing `time`  by reference bugs me a bit.  It should work, but try passing by value instead and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Just a guess but...lifetime of `str`....and `time` (^^^)

Comment: @VaughnCato: I tried but nothing changed, but thanks for your suggestion anyway ;-)

Comment: Try passing the string by value also.

Comment: @VaughnCato yap I already did, but nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

I try under Ubuntu 16.04 and get no errors. But if you really wanna pass arguments by reference, then they should be wrapped in std::ref.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're passing a temporary const reference, constructed from a const char[] through the thread creation constructor... The lifetime of this temporary is guaranteed until the std::thread constructor returns, which means it will most likely be destroyed before the child thread has a chance to access it.

This also applies to your integer parameter, which will manifest a more bizarre set of symptoms, considering it probably is only an immediate sitting in a CPU register.

In order to properly solve your problem, either have your thread function take parameters by value (so that a local copy of them exists), or pass objects defined at the proper scope into the thread constructor by reference using std::ref().

Answer (score 0):

The reason that works in newer Ubuntu versions is the std::string implementation changed from using a reference counting scheme to one using short-string-optimization. I believe the change was made with the GCC 5.1 compiler... If you pass a string longer than 24 characters long through the std::thread constructor, i would expect you to still see similar results.